# How does a rect affect css nth-child?

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I created an SVG using D3.  I am now trying to style it differently using the `nth-child` css selector.

```css
.strat {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.strat .bar-circles:nth-child(1n+0) circle {
    fill: #00688d;
}

.strat .bar-circles:nth-child(2n+0) circle {
    fill: #00a4a5;
}

.strat .bar-circles:nth-child(3n+0) circle {
    fill: #f7b454;
}

.strat .css-fix {
    stroke: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<h5>Broken Nth Child</h5>
<div class="strat"><svg height="380" width="800" fill="#fff"><rect x="0" y="0" height="400" width="800" stroke="#fff" fill="#fff" class="chart-background"></rect><text x="140" y="100" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="end">0</text><text x="660" y="100" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="start">89%</text><circle r="2" cx="150" cy="97" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><line x1="150" x2="650" y1="97" y2="97" stroke="#999" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3,3" fill="#fff"></line><circle r="2" cx="650" cy="97" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><g class="bar-circles"><circle r="30" cx="240.34792368125704" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle><circle r="30" cx="262.7946127946128" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="273.4567901234568" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="253.8159371492705" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle><circle r="30" cx="262.7946127946128" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="256.06060606060606" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle><circle r="30" cx="266.16161616161617" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="257.74410774410774" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle><circle r="30" cx="264.4781144781145" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle></g><rect x="259.73936899862827" y="65" height="70" width="2" stroke-width="4" stroke="transparent" fill="#000" data-plugin="tooltip" data-title="Avg Read Rate<br />20%"></rect><text x="140" y="220" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="end">0</text><text x="660" y="220" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="start">89%</text><circle r="2" cx="150" cy="217" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><line x1="150" x2="650" y1="217" y2="217" stroke="#999" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3,3" fill="#fff"></line><circle r="2" cx="650" cy="217" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><g class="bar-circles"></g><text x="140" y="340" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="end">0</text><text x="660" y="340" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="start">89%</text><circle r="2" cx="150" cy="337" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><line x1="150" x2="650" y1="337" y2="337" stroke="#999" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3,3" fill="#fff"></line><circle r="2" cx="650" cy="337" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><g class="bar-circles"><circle r="30" cx="210.60606060606062" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="223.51290684624018" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="229.12457912457913" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="228.00224466891135" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="232.4915824915825" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle><circle r="30" cx="229.68574635241305" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="219.02356902356902" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="225.75757575757575" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="230.2469135802469" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle><circle r="30" cx="210.04489337822673" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle><circle r="30" cx="223.51290684624018" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle></g><rect x="223.8189980614223" y="305" height="70" width="2" stroke-width="4" stroke="transparent" fill="#000" data-plugin="tooltip" data-title="Avg Read Rate<br />13%" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></rect></svg></div>


<h5>Working Nth Child</h5>
<div class="strat"><svg height="380" width="800" fill="#fff"><rect x="0" y="0" height="400" width="800" stroke="#fff" fill="#fff" class="chart-background"></rect><text x="140" y="100" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="end">0</text><text x="660" y="100" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="start">89%</text><circle r="2" cx="150" cy="97" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><line x1="150" x2="650" y1="97" y2="97" stroke="#999" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3,3" fill="#fff"></line><circle r="2" cx="650" cy="97" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><g class="bar-circles"><circle r="30" cx="240.34792368125704" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle><circle r="30" cx="262.7946127946128" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="273.4567901234568" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="253.8159371492705" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle><circle r="30" cx="262.7946127946128" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="256.06060606060606" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle><circle r="30" cx="266.16161616161617" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="257.74410774410774" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle><circle r="30" cx="264.4781144781145" cy="97" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle></g><rect x="259.73936899862827" y="65" height="70" width="2" stroke-width="4" stroke="transparent" fill="#000" data-plugin="tooltip" data-title="Avg Read Rate<br />20%"></rect><text x="140" y="220" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="end">0</text><text x="660" y="220" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="start">89%</text><circle r="2" cx="150" cy="217" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><line x1="150" x2="650" y1="217" y2="217" stroke="#999" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3,3" fill="#fff"></line><circle r="2" cx="650" cy="217" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><g class="bar-circles"></g><rect x="200" y="185" height="70" width="2" class="css-fix"></rect><text x="140" y="340" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="end">0</text><text x="660" y="340" font-size="10px" fill="#999" text-anchor="start">89%</text><circle r="2" cx="150" cy="337" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><line x1="150" x2="650" y1="337" y2="337" stroke="#999" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3,3" fill="#fff"></line><circle r="2" cx="650" cy="337" opacity="1" fill="#999"></circle><g class="bar-circles"><circle r="30" cx="210.60606060606062" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="223.51290684624018" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="229.12457912457913" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="228.00224466891135" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="232.4915824915825" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="229.68574635241305" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="219.02356902356902" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="225.75757575757575" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="230.2469135802469" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="210.04489337822673" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1"></circle><circle r="30" cx="223.51290684624018" cy="337" opacity="0.4" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0" class="bulk" data-plugin="popover" data-title="" data-content="" fill="#27a9e1" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></circle></g><rect x="223.8189980614223" y="305" height="70" width="2" stroke-width="4" stroke="transparent" fill="#000" data-plugin="tooltip" data-title="Avg Read Rate<br />13%" data-original-title="" title="" data-has-tip="true"></rect></svg></div>
```

In my case the second row is missing data (and would have green circles), and the last row should be yellow circles.

The inclusion of the rect `.css-fix` (highlighted in pink) fixes the css nth-child selector (and correclty changes the last row of circles to yellow), but why?

I tried quite a number of things. I created an empty circle in the middle row (inside `.bar-circles` element) because I understand the `g` element is a non-positioning element. I also played with other elements inside the `g`, but I don't understand why having the `rect` element fixes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot restrict `:nth-child` in any way, neither to a specific *element type* (-> type selector), nor to elements with a certain *class* (-> class selector, as in your example), nor attribute (-> attribute selector).

Really ***all*** it can do for you is **ask this one question**:

## "Am I the nth child of my parent element?"

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: yep, for this usecase, there is :nth-of-type()
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp